# Style dropdown items with different colors

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style each option in a dropdown with a different color. I've tried two approaches:

```
<option style="color: red;" value="KellerWilliamsRed">Keller Williams Red</option>
```

And...

```
<option class="dilbeck" value="DilbeckGreen">Dilbeck Green</option>
.dilbeck {color: green}
```

For some reason though, the text is not colored, and I'm stumped...

You can see the dropdown here: http://dailyspiro.com/lp/LP.html

Comment: i'm able to see the colored text..

Comment: What browser are you using? Works for me

Comment: Don't link to your website. Instead, link to a JSFiddle and provide the requisite code here. Look up CSS rules and what `color` property applies to. And search for "how can I apply a color to a font".

Comment: Does not work for me and probably never will (Latest chrome on Mac OS X).  At least on mac, you can't style the `option` font color because it uses the system standard for styling drop downs.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, that must be it. I wonder if there's a way around this?

Comment: Often with drop downs, people customize element to 'appear' like drop downs at run-time, while leaving the original select boxes hidden.  This allows total customization.  This [link](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/) won't answer your question directly but does give an example of what I mean.  You could follow a similar concept.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/36U4u/)**</kbd>

```
select option:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}
select option:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
select option:nth-child(3) {
  color: green;
}
```